# Get the file extension (basename?) 

Tags: php, file

If I have a code like this:

```
$file = basename($filename);
```

How do I get the file extension of `$file`? The variable `$file` could contain any kind of file, like `index.php` or `test.jpeg`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";
```

or simply:

```
echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

You can of course look for the last "." in the filename and get everything after (relatively easy) but why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 5):

```
pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```